# What does i = i&1 mean in C programming language?

Tags: c, loops, gcc, syntax

I got this sample code and I really do not understand how does it work. It is compiled by GCC and there are no errors at all.

Also, can you please tell me what this piece of code "***i = i&1***" does? Thank you!

```
int main(void){
  int i;
  for (i = 5; i--; i = i&1) {
    puts("iteration"); 
  }
  printf("%d\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is:

> iteration
>
> -1

Comment: It's a peculiar way to write a `for` loop. The second expression usually tests the loop iterator at the start of each loop, the third usually modifies it at the end of each loop. Writing trick loops and then asking "how does this work" is not good.

Comment: This code is for study purposes and it is not written by me. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: 'i' is called before the loop and will run fine through g++. This is an indicator for index manipulations. I've seen three go by and am not sure how to tool code like that. Interesting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the begin of the for-Loop:

- i is set to 5

Next step is: Check i--, which means:

- First: i = 5 > 0 => true
- Second: set i to i - 1 => i = 4

Next step: do the inner block.

Next step: i = i & 1, which results in:

- 4&1 => 0100 & 0001 => i = 0

Next step: Check i--

- First: i = 0 => false
- Second: set i to i - 1 => i = -1

Answer (score 5):

`&` is `bitwise AND` operator

```
i = i&1 // this AND's bits of i to bits of value 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`i = i&1` will extract the least significant bit of `i` as `&` is the `bitwise AND` operator.

However, the program you've written is Undefined Behavior (error with g++). This is because you define `i` in the `for` loop, and once the loop ends, `i` goes out of scope. So printing it afterwards in the next line gives an error.

Coming to your code, I would seriously love to know where you saw it, cause it seems horrible to me. The conditions of the `for` loop seem convoluted, and I can't explain how the loop will run (which is probably not a good thing).

Comment: I have fixed that. And thank you for your fast response.

Comment: We have got this piece of code on exam. It is kind of catch question where you have to determine number of iterations and value of i variable.

Comment: `i & 1` is not  equivalent to `i % 2`.  Try it with `i = -1`.

Comment: @chux : Thank you, fixed it.